# List of Dates - Finding Aging Between the Dates

Tags: sql, salesforce, amazon-redshift

I am writing a query to retrieve aging data from `case_history` table (from salesforce). As case is worked on by the team, the case goes through different stages such as new, working, quality check, please correct and closed.

```
Case_id  |  Edit_Date           |   Field  |    Old_Value      |    New_Value    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
xvywiqhn |  2019-12-12 08:05:59 |   Status |    Quality Check  |    Closed
xvywiqhn |  2019-12-12 07:21:55 |   Status |    Please Correct |    Quality Check
xvywiqhn |  2019-12-09 08:32:40 |   Status |    Quality Check  |    Please Correct
xvywiqhn |  2019-12-09 08:08:49 |   Status |    Working        |    Quality Check
xvywiqhn |  2019-12-09 07:35:24 |   Status |    New            |    Working
```

I am trying to get created columns in such a way that I get the next date and new_value so that I can get aging for that stage.

```
Case_id  |  Edit_Date           | Old_Value      | New_Value      | Completion_Date     | End_Stage      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
xvywiqhn |  2019-12-12 08:05:59 | Quality Check  | Closed         | NULL                | NULL 
xvywiqhn |  2019-12-12 07:21:55 | Please Correct | Quality Check  | 2019-12-12 08:05:59 | Closed
xvywiqhn |  2019-12-09 08:32:40 | Quality Check  | Please Correct | 2019-12-12 07:21:55 | Quality Check
xvywiqhn |  2019-12-09 08:08:49 | Working        | Quality Check  | 2019-12-09 08:32:40 | Please Correct
xvywiqhn |  2019-12-09 07:35:24 | New            | Working        | 2019-12-09 08:08:49 | Quality Check
```

Is there a way I can do this?

```
SELECT
    case_id,
    edit_date,
    old_value,
    new_value,
    "getting next edit_date",
    "getting new_value for next edit_date"
FROM case_history
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try using the `LAG` function here:

```
SELECT
    case_id,
    edit_date,
    old_value,
    new_value,
    LAG(edit_date) OVER (PARTITION BY case_id ORDER BY edit_date) completion_date,
    LAG(new_value) OVER (PARTITION BY case_id ORDER BY edit_date) end_stage
FROM case_history
ORDER BY
    case_id,
    edit_date;
```

Comment: Thank you! This gave me another idea. Instead of LAG, I am able to get the result I need if I use LEAD.

Answer (score 0):

Think I figured out how to do it

```
SELECT
    case_id,
    edit_date,
    old_value,
    new_value,
    first_value(edit_date) over (partition by case_id order by edit_date rows BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) Completion_Date,
    first_value(new_value) over (partition by case_id order by edit_date rows BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) End_Stage
FROM case_history
```

Comment: I don't know if the full `BETWEEN` window you included be necessary, but even if not, I would probably just keep it simple and use `LAG/LEAD` here.